# Adding up hours if employee has multiple submissions in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Creating a report that shows the hours employees worked over a date range.  The problem I have is that I am not sure how I would get the sum of all the hours, then display one row for each employee with their total hours.  Picture of what I have below.
[image]

Here is what I want it to look like.
[image]

ReportsController.cs

```
        /// <summary>Gets the timecards report view as an asynchronous operation.</summary>
    /// <param name="model">The reports view model.</param>
    /// <returns>The timecards report view.</returns>
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Hours")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> HoursAsync(HoursViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DateRange dateRange = DateRange.Parse(model.Dates, " - ");
            DateTime startDateUtc = dateRange.Start.ToUniversalTime().Date;
            DateTime endDateUtc = dateRange.End.ToUniversalTime().AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);

            // Get all timecards for the given date range.
            List<Timecard> timecards = await _Context.Timecards
                .Include(t => t.Employee)
                .Where(t => t.PunchInDateUtc <= endDateUtc && startDateUtc <= t.PunchOutDateUtc)
                .OrderBy(t => t.PunchInDateUtc)
                .ToListAsync();

            // Map the domain objects to the view model.
            model.Items = timecards.Select(t =>
            {
                return new HoursItemViewModel
                {
                    EmployeeId = t.Employee.Id,
                    Employee = $"{t.Employee.FirstName} {t.Employee.LastName}",
                    Hours = (t.PunchOutDateUtc - t.PunchInDateUtc)?.TotalHours ?? 0
                };
            }).ToList();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Hours.cshtml

```
<div class="m-portlet__body table-responsive">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <table class="table m-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Items.FirstOrDefault().Employee)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Items.FirstOrDefault().Hours)
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    <tr><td colspan="5" class="text-center">No records found</td></tr>
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Items)
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

HoursItemViewModel.cshtml

```
    @model SentryCrane.AdminApp.Models.ReportViewModels.HoursItemViewModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(Model.Employee, "Details", "Employees", routeValues: new { id = Model.EmployeeId }, htmlAttributes: null)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Hours)
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am pretty new to C# and MVC apps, so let me know if I missed anything you would need in order to help me out.  Thanks!

Comment: should `t.PunchInDateUtc <= endDateUtc` not be  `t.PunchInDateUtc >= startDateUtc` and same for the other ? (reversed)

Comment: The punch in date has to be earlier than the end date.  The punch out date has to be later than the start date.  Or at least that is the idea.  Changing it to what you mentioned provide no results, as expected.

Comment: Well to be clear, you would want BOTH those dates in between right? (and how do you account for someone punched in but not yet punched out or someone punched in before the start time and punched out in the middle (crosses either time boundary)

Comment: Sorry to jump away from your question, but you prove good points.  For now, I am hoping I can solve the issue at hand.  I saw something about groupby, so I am going to see if I can find anything on that and incorporate it into my app.  I feel like setting up an if or foreach loop before I generate the list would work, but I have no idea how I would code that.  I'm going to keep on studying what I can, but any help or hints are definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your last statement which is populating Model.Items in ReportsController.cs Action as below:

```
        // Map the domain objects to the view model.
        model.Items = timecards.Select(t =>new HoursItemViewModel
            {
                EmployeeId = t.Employee.Id,
                Employee = $"{t.Employee.FirstName} {t.Employee.LastName}",
                Hours = (t.PunchOutDateUtc - t.PunchInDateUtc)?.TotalHours ?? 0
            }).GroupBy(i => i.EmployeeId).Select(g => new HoursItemViewModel
        {
            EmployeeId = g.FirstOrDefault().EmployeeId, EmployeeName = g.FirstOrDefault().EmployeeName,
            Hours = g.Sum(i => i.Hours)
        }).ToList();
```

Instead of grouping on ViewModel, you can also group on your domain objects and get the final results (did not test the below code but you will get idea of what I meant)

```
// Map the domain objects to the view model.
model.Items = timecards.Select(t => t.Employee).ToList().GroupBy(e => e.Id).Select(g => new HoursItemViewModel
  {
       EmployeeId = g.FirstOrDefault().EmployeeId, 
       EmployeeName =  $"{g.FirstOrDefault().FirstName,.FirstName} {g.FirstOrDefault().LastName}",
       Hours = g.Sum(i => (i.PunchOutDateUtc - i.PunchInDateUtc)?.TotalHours ?? 0)
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Appreciate showing how I would be able to group it two different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Get your list of hours/fractions of hours (starttime or punch in time) `TimeFrom` (end time or punch out time) `TimeTo` whichever brackets the time then something like

```
 .Select(c => c.TimeTo - c.TimeFrom)
 .Aggregate( (working, next) => working.Add(next) )
 .TotalHours
```

Comment: You can then decide how you want to round or format from that

Comment: This does NOT account for people punched in before the start AND punched out after, a "full day" sort of